# trackpad doesn't work after suspend

Tags: touchpad, suspend, synaptics

Ubuntu 14.04 and a Fujitsu Lifebook U-series.I can't get trackpad to work after suspend bluetooth mouse does.Sorry to say that trackpad didn't work form the beginning but my son googled something and edited something and got it to work. Trackpad works fine if I reboot or start the computer from scratch, two finger scrolling and so forth. Need some help to search what goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem as well, what I found works for me is switching to text console and back.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> switches you to text console 1.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> switches you back to your desktop. If not, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: Alt+F7 (or Alt+F8 in the rare situation where [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) runs on tty8) is sufficient to switch *away* from a non-graphical [virtual console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console). It works fine with Ctrl too, but holding down Ctrl is only needed when switching away from a graphical virtual console (i.e., one that has [X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) running on it).